# static string constants in class vs namespace for constants [c++]

Tags: c++, namespaces, constants, string-constant

I want to declare string constants that will be used **across various** classes in the project. I am considering two alternatives

Option 1:

```
#header file 
class constants{
    static const string const1;
};

#cpp file

const string constants::const1="blah";
```

Option 2:

```
#header file 
namespace constants{
    static const string const1="blah";
};
```

Just wondering what would be a better implementation.

Already looked at

> [Where to store Class Specific named constants in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299765/where-to-store-class-specific-named-constants-in-c)
>
> [Where to put constant strings in C++: static class members or anonymous namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465546/where-to-put-constant-strings-in-c-static-class-members-or-anonymous-namespace)

---

UPDATE:

Option 3:

Based on the suggestions from  "potatoswatter" and "sellibitze" i currently have the following implementation?

```
#header file
namespace constants{
    extern const string& const1(); //WORKS WITHOUT THE EXTERN  ***WHY***
};

#cpp file
namespace constants{
   const string& const1(){static string* str = new string ("blah"); return *str;}
}
```

I'm including the header file where i need to use the constants. Are there any major cons of this implementation?

Comment: Option 2 doesn't appear to be a solution. The strings will still be defined separately for each source file, despite appearing in the same namespace.

Comment: Option 2 is a solution if Shishya actually gets the syntax for it correct. (No 'static', and the string can only be declared in the header, but will need to be defined in a source file.)

Comment: @pkh: syntax is a little trickier than that ;v)

Comment: Eh, forgot the extern. Not really "tricky," though.

Comment: The update looks fine. `extern` is strictly optional in a function declaration, so that's why it works equally either way. You don't need to use `new`, though. `{ static string str( "blah" ); return str; }` is the usual methodology.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<sup>Update 2 years later:</sup>

Every global accessible by more than one source file should be wrapped in an `inline` function so the linker shares the object between the files, and the program initializes it properly.

```
inline std::string const &const1() {
    static std::string ret = "hello, world!";
    return ret;
}
```

The `inline` function is implicitly `extern` and may be wrapped in a named namespace or a class, if you like. (But don't use a class just to hold static members, as namespaces are better for that. And don't use an anonymous namespace as that would defeat the linker, and each source would see a different `std::string` object.)

Comment: It'll be cleaner in the presence of multiple constants to use namespace constants { ... } in the source file.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: $2.13.4/2- Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementationdefined. The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined. So even if they are defined separately, they may not really occupy as much distinct space in memory if that was the concern.

Comment: @Chubsdad: The only string literals in OP's code are the initializers to `std::string`. I was referring to the `std::string` objects.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: When u say use c string literals are you suggesting that i replace the std::string with char*? Also how would i avoid the Static Initialization Order Fiasco?

Comment: @Shishya: Yes. Of course, it depends whether you really need `std::string` or not. See that page on how to avoid it. You need to create a function to return the global, instead of directly accessing the global. So, if the reason for `std::string` is localization, there could be a function `std::string const& get_localized_string( int string_index )` which simply returns the globals. That solves the initialization order problem.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Localization is not a concern to me for this project. But i'm c++ newbie, so im not quite clear on why switching to char* would solve the SIOF problem.

Comment: @Shishya: `std::string` is an object with a constructor, so it's invalid before the constructor is called. On the other hand, a string literal is just raw data built into the application binary, and it's required to be valid before any C++ code runs at all. Being initialized by the OS, not C++, it's completely outside the SIOF.

Comment: @Potataswatter: please comment on the update where i have listed my current impl based on your suggestion.

Comment: Aren't the parenthesis missing? After the name of the function and before the bracket `inline std::string const &const1 () {`.

Answer (score 12):

All answers that resort to `std::string` run the risk of dynamically allocating memory for a string literal which is going to remain constant throughout the lifetime of the program (and the binary), so they should be avoided.

[sellibitze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3671531/183120)'s answer comes close but it has the problem of declaring it once and then defining it elsewhere, which I don't find elegant and is more work. The best way would be

```
namespace constants {
    const char * const blah = "blah!"
    const char * const yada = "yada yada!"
}
```

This is solution is discussed further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2879851/183120).

Answer (score 9):

Neither. I'd go with this:

```
// header file
namespace constants {
extern const char const1[];
}

// cpp file
namespace constants {
extern const char const1[] = "blah";
}
```

The header file contains a declaration of `const1` with incomplete type but convertible to `char const*` and the cpp-file contains a definition of the character array with external linkage. There is no dynamic initialization like you have with `std::string`. So, that's a plus, IMHO.

Comment: Shouldn't the code in the .cpp be this instead? `const char constants::const1[] = "blah";`, ie: no `extern` and no `namespace` redeclaration.

Comment: @Remy: *shrug*. Do whatever you like. But there's nothing wrong with the code I posted. You can remove `extern` in the cpp file if you include the header which already declares `const1` to have external linkage. But since in C++ constant variables at namespace scope have internal linkage by default you need to have at least one `extern` in there. What I posted also works without including the header in the cpp file, btw.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1 achieves the same as Option 2, but in a messier way.

If you're going to use a class that just has static members, especially for global access/constants, use a namespace.