# Should I prefer static const variables at class or namespace scope?

Tags: c++

Does one have any tangible benefits over the other? I've started using the latter because it doesn't pollute the header file with static const declarations, so it's a bit easier to read. I'm often using these constants in only a couple of member functions.

**Class scope:**

*.hpp*

```
class MyType 
{
private:
    static const std::wstring kFoo;
}
```

*.cpp*

```
const wstring MyType::kFoo(L"foo");
...
void MyType::parse(const wstring& input)
{
    if (input == kFoo) { do1; }  
    ...
}
```

**versus**

**namespace scope**

*.cpp*

```
const wstring kFoo(L"foo");
...
void MyType::parse(const wstring& input)
{
    if (input == kFoo) { do1; }  
    ...
}
```

Comment: Part of it is really a question of portability: do you want other applications to be able to access your static const values?

Comment: Keep them in your class if they're related (only) to that class. If they're not related to a particular class, keep them in a namespace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [static string constants in class vs namespace for constants \[c++\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670031/static-string-constants-in-class-vs-namespace-for-constants-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all,

```
const wstring kFoo(L"foo");
```

is in global scope, not in a `namespace`. You can easily wrap that in an anonymous `namespace`.

```
namespace
{
   const wstring kFoo(L"foo");
}
```

Coming to the question of whether it is better to use `static` member of the class or a member in a `namespace`, the answer depends on team coding style guidelines as well as personal preferences.

My suggestion would be to put it under the anonymous `namespace` in the .cpp file. That way, it can remain an implementation detail and the class definition is not polluted by an implementation detail.

**PS**

Please note that the question [static string constants in class vs namespace for constants [c++]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670031/static-string-constants-in-class-vs-namespace-for-constants-c) addreses the issue but with a difference. In the other post, the user wants to share the `static` member variable across multiple files. In your post you have explicitly put the `static` member variable as a `private` member, and hence not to be shared acrosss files. If that assessment is incorrect, your question is a duplicate of the other question and deserved to be closed as such.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been leaning towards also. And yes you are correct in your PS assumption, this is different than that question.